# MSTest for huge legacy codebase

Tags: c++, mstest, legacy, googletest

we have a huge codebase with about 1000k lines of native/unmanaged legacy c++ - code and we are going to provide the code with unit tests and MSTest would fit perfectly in our current development environment (TFS, VS 2010, ...). I know that MSTest is orginally meant to test managed code but its also possible to write unit tests for unmanaged sc.

Are there any (later) drawbacks on the usage of MSTest for unmanaged code? Does anyone have any experience on this?

The second opinion would be using Google.Test, but I would have to write a Visual Studio add-in to integrate the gtest framework in our environment.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: After all we decided to drop MSTest and we now use GoogleTest as unit-test framework. The reason is that it would take too much time and efford to get our codebase compiled under /CLR:pure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not recommend MSTest for managed testing. See [here](http://preetsangha.blogspot.com) for my experiences. However if you do insist I would say a really good way to test you legacy code would be use [PInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx) interop to your c++ code.

Comment: Do you have any experience on how Visual Studio enhances the process of testing unmanaged code? I read once in a blog that this should be improved with the new VS version

Answer (score 1):

**I would recommend [googletest](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/) anyway.** I think they will also gladly accept your VS integration and include it in the next release, provided the patch has reasonable quality.

Oh, and you can use another great Google project then, [gmock](http://code.google.com/p/gmock/).

Answer (score 0):

I use the Boost.Test framework to test my C++ code in Visual Studio without any issues.  You need to create a test project (a console-mode EXE) that contains your tests which your main project can depend on.  Using the Visual Studio 'post build' step you can run the tests automatically.

Comment: thank you for your comment. test automation is only a one of our "must haves", furthermore the test framework should be directly integrated into VS, e.g. the user should be able to select the tests he/she wants to run or it should deliver useful information like code coverage etc.